# Trying to install Minecraft on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, minecraft

I am trying to install Minecraft on Ubuntu 16.04. These are what I'm using in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

However, when I do the: sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package minecraft-installer
```

Has anyone else successfully installed Minecraft on this version of Ubuntu, if so how? And why am I getting that error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All I did was go to: https://minecraft.net/download and select "Show All Platforms".  Next I clicked and downloaded the Minecraft.jar file.  Thats it.
Just be sure you have Java installed.  You also may need to click the Minecraft.jar file properties and change the file to launch as an executable.

There may be other ways but this has worked for me.

Comment: I installed both and I checked to make sure it executable, but it doesn't do anything when I double click. It opens up the folder. /:

Comment: Here is a walkthrough for this method: http://feeblenerd.blogspot.com/2015/09/install-minecraft-on-lubuntu.html

Comment: @wattahay: You should copy & paste the steps from that link and put it as a new answer. It's very handy.

Comment: There is on longer a Minecraft.jar file on minecraft.net/download

Answer (score 4):

Minecraft is now available as a [snap](https://snapcraft.io/minecraft) in the store, so you can open Ubuntu Software, search for Minecraft and click 'Install'. Alternative you can install via the terminal with one line:-

```
snap install minecraft
```

The 'home' directory for the minecraft snap is `~/snap/minecraft/common/` so that's where you'll find the `.minecraft` folder in case you want to add mods.

Comment: This snap doesn't seem to exist anymore, but "mc-installer" does: https://snapcraft.io/install/mc-installer/debian

Answer (score 2):

If you have both Java and Minecraft.jar installed, try this. This assumes that Minecraft.jar is in your user's Downloads directory:

- Open a Terminal window: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Navigate to the directory where Minecraft.jar is by typing: `cd ~/Downloads`
- Run Minecraft by typing: `java -jar ./Minecraft.jar`

Comment: This works. But Now I have a ugly Icon. I added a `minecraft.desktop` with the correct data. Which adds a icon to the loader. But will disappear when pressing the "play" button. Any idea's?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue which was fixed by changing the distribution name to "trusty" in the edit sources tab

system settings / Software & updates / Other Software tab

select http://ppa.launchpad.net/minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer/ubuntu

then edit and change the field distribution to "trusty" then you run again the following

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```