# Lost on these new fresh install upgrade-update errors on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, updates, sudo

Ubuntu Gnome 17.04; upgraded from 14.04 LTS and for some reason this nonsense is all over my terminal when I do

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get
```

I get

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I never saw this before on 14.04LTS (although I admit, I have been away from Ubuntu for about two years); I even lost my username and password apparently so pardon me for this new account. I tried all of my emails, but no go so here be my new account. Yay me!

Back to the question; any idea why I am getting all of this? And who the heck is jonathonf? Thinking maybe it is an old 14.04 rep that is no longer supported? This is a fresh install with only a few programs and Minecraft installed for the kiddos.

Comment: Does `minecraft-installer` have a bersion for Ubuntu Zesty?

Comment: ok `jonathonf` is the maintainer of the repo that's tearing up your screen, then I can't the installer for Ubuntu Zesty... Remove it and it all go away...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Removing errros

[“Minecraft Installer Peeps” team](https://launchpad.net/%7Eminecraft-installer-peeps/+archive/ubuntu/minecraft-installer) and [Jonathon F](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6) doesn't have a release targeting Zesty yet.

I'd advise you to run these following commands to get rid of the errors

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

#### Installing the packages you want

If you want to get `python 3.6` on 17.04, then you don't need to add PPA, it's already available on Universe repository

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

And Minecraft is officially available as `.jar` file on [their website](https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/)

---

#### References and extra information

[How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

[How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

[Trying to install Minecraft on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764147/trying-to-install-minecraft-on-ubuntu-16-04)

[How to install a .jar file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372762/how-to-install-a-jar-file)

Comment: I had just finished un-installing them (took me a few to remember how) when I saw your post. Your way was much easier, I went through Software & Updates. Thank you, I am remembering a lot more now.

For the Python I am not sure how that ppa got in there. I installed it just as you advised. Maybe I tried something before that, I had installed so much I don't remember.

Good looking out, thank you so much!!!

jth

Comment: @java.the.hutt **If** my answer worked for you then please accept or upvote the answer, you can also choose to wait for better answers on the question ;)

Comment: Sorry about that, I had slept in. Thanks for the nudge to get me up and running this morning.